# JFileChooser in java

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm french so my English is not beautiful.
My problem is that my second window JfileChooser does not open when I launch my program.
I don't understand why. Could you please help me?

My main class:

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ged;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

/**
 *
 * @author Evan
 */
public class GED {
    private static String Nom_Client;
    private static String N_plan;
    private static String ind;
    private static String Reference;
    private static String Typologie;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO code application logic here

        System.out.println("****************** TPS Gestionnaire ******************");
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("Quel fichier choisissez vous ?");

        JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
        file.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        file.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
            int retour = file.showOpenDialog(null);
                if(retour == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                {
                    File[] fichier=file.getSelectedFiles();
                        for( int i = 1; i<fichier.length; ++i)
                        { 
                        fichier[i].getName();    
                        fichier[i].getAbsolutePath();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Fichier choisi : " + file.getSelectedFile().getName());
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Aucun de fichier choisi");
                }       

        System.out.println (" ");

        System.out.println("Veuillez indiquer le nom du client");
        Scanner name = new Scanner (System.in);
        String Nom_Client = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println("L'entreprise est: " + Nom_Client.toUpperCase());

        System.out.println ("Dans quel sous doussier souhaitez vous mettre votre document ?");
        System.out.println (" ");
        System.out.println ("1." + " PV Contrôle ");
        System.out.println ("2." + " Plan ");

        Scanner sr = new Scanner (System.in);
        int i = sr.nextInt();
        Categorie c = new Categorie (Nom_Client.toUpperCase(),"0","0","0","0");
        if (i==1)
            {
                c.PVControle();
            }
        else
            {  
                c.Plan();

                System.out.println (" Veuillez choisir la nouvelle destination du fichier");
                System.out.println(" ");
                Parcourir e = new Parcourir();
                e.Enregistrer();

            }

    }

}
```

**my Parcourir class:**

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ged;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

/**
 *
 * @author Evan
 */
public class Parcourir {

    public void Enregistrer() throws IOException

        {
                JFileChooser newdestination = new JFileChooser();
                newdestination.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/Users/Evan/"));//Chemin
                newdestination.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                newdestination.showOpenDialog(null);

                newdestination.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
                int dest = newdestination.showOpenDialog(null);
                    if(dest == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                    {
                    File[] fichier02=newdestination.getSelectedFiles();
                        for(int t = 1; t<fichier02.length; ++t)
                        { 
                        fichier02[t].getName();    
                        fichier02[t].getAbsolutePath();
                        }
                    System.out.println("Destination choisie : " + newdestination.getSelectedFile().getName());

                    /*File source = file.getSelectedFile(); //Permet de récupérer le chemin du début
                    File destination = new File (newdestination.getSelectedFile() + Nom_Client.toUpperCase()+" "+ c.getN_plan()+ " " + "Ind" + " "+ c.getind().toUpperCase() +".pdf"); // Permet d'avoir la nouvelle destination avec le fichier renommé
                    source.renameTo(destination); //Pas encore corrigé
                    System.out.println(" Votre fichier à été renommé puis déplacé");   */     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    System.out.println("Aucune destination choisie");
                    }
        }        

}
```

And my Catégorie class:

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ged;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

/**
 *
 * @author Evan
 */
public class Categorie {
    private String Nom_Client;
    private String N_plan;
    private String ind;
    private String Reference;
    private String Typologie;


    public Categorie(String Nom_Client, String N_plan, String ind, String Reference, String Typologie) {
        this.Nom_Client = Nom_Client;
        this.N_plan = N_plan;
        this.ind = ind;
        this.Reference = Reference;
        this.Typologie = Typologie;
    }


    public void PVControle () throws IOException{

        int t = 0;
        System.out.println("Vous avez choisit la catégorie PV de contrôle");
        System.out.println("Veuillez indiquer la référence produit");
        Scanner ref = new Scanner (System.in);
        this.Reference = ref.nextLine(); //Permet de demander la reference du plan
        System.out.println("Ainsi que la typologie de production");
        System.out.println("1." + "TÔLES");
        System.out.println("2." + "BOB");
        Scanner typ = new Scanner (System.in);
        this.Typologie = ref.nextLine(); //Permet de demander la typologie

        if ( t == 1)
            {

                System.out.println (" Vous avez choisit la typologie TÔLES ");
                this.Typologie = "TÔLES";
            }

        else 
            {
                System.out.println(" Vous avez choisit la typologie BOB ");
                this.Typologie = "BOB";
            }

        System.out.println("Le nom du fichier est: " +Nom_Client + " " + "REF" + " " + Reference.toUpperCase() + " " + "-" + " " + Typologie);    
    }

    public void Plan () throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Vous avez choisit la catégorie Plan");        
        System.out.println("Veuillez indiquer le n° Plan");
        Scanner plan = new Scanner (System.in);
        N_plan = plan.nextLine(); //Permet de demander le n°Plan        
        System.out.println ("Ainsi que l'IND");
        Scanner IND = new Scanner (System.in);//Demande de l'IND
        ind = IND.nextLine();        
        System.out.println("Le nom du fichier est: " +Nom_Client + " " + N_plan + " " + "Ind" +" " + ind.toUpperCase());        

    }


    public String getN_plan()
    {
     return N_plan;
    }

    public String getind()
    {
        return ind;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Fast Snail: No i dont have any errors

Comment: Danio, the first windows is at the beginning of the main class and the second is in Parcourir class and is ask at the end of the main class: Parcourir e = new Parcourir();
                e.Enregistrer();

Comment: @ Evan Martho i can't test your exact code because don't know what is `Categorie` class how ever it works for me

Comment: @FastSnail i add the catégorie class

Comment: @FastSnail No, i did input 2 to the console for have the second window

Comment: you call `Plan()` method .it wait you to input .after you see `Le nom du fichier est` in the console file dialog will open.i can't undestand the text because it's not english .if you expect file dialog to open just after you input 2 ,test by commenting line `// c.Plan();`

Comment: @FastSnail no it's always the same...

Comment: see this i'm getting second window http://i.imgur.com/PalDPji.gif

Comment: @FastSnail :O 
How you succeed ?

Comment: i don't know why it doesn't work for you .but it should work

Comment: you keep the same code or not ?

Comment: it's good, i reinstalled jdk 8 and i have my second window but i must to click two times on OK for the windows stops

Comment: me too.i also clicked 2 times you see my gif

Comment: you call file dialog 2 times in `Enregistrer` method .`newdestination.showOpenDialog(null);` and  `int dest = newdestination.showOpenDialog(null);` you need to  remove `newdestination.showOpenDialog(null);`

Comment: yes thanks you ! My second windows open not all times...

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your Scanner, the second window will only open after you feed your Scanner with some input (pressing Enter). I tried and the second dialog opened after you feed the Scanner twice.

Comment: Can you explain, because i dont understand please

Comment: Launch the program, select the file and click the Open button, enter the client name, press enter, input 2 (Plan) and press Enter, and the second dialog will open.

Comment: Why ? I need to delete something ?

Comment: What exactly do you do when you launch the application, what are the steps ?

Comment: i launch with your advice, it was good and now i launch again and the second window does not open again..

Comment: I want to first get the file I want, then I ask the name of the client, if the category is flat so I ask her plan number and index and then I open a new window to choose or I want to record the file to be renamed in the end.

Comment: - Launch the application, select a file, and click the open button: it will ask for the client name. - Input the client name and press Enter: it will ask for the sub-folder. - Input 2 and press Enter: it will ask for the plan number. - Input a number and press Enter: it asks for the IND. - Input something again and press Enter again: the second window will open.

Comment: after the ind i press enter and a second times ?

Comment: Yes, you need to that each time you use Scanner and read input with nextLine.

Comment: Is there an easier solution than this one? For my program to work correctly

Comment: If you don't want to have to press Enter so many times don't use Scanner. You could show a dialog asking for the data or something else, it's up to you.

Comment: What can replace a scanner?

Comment: And http://hpics.li/c3ec079

my second window does not open when i press two times enter..

Comment: That's weird after 'Veuillez choisir la nouvelle destination du fichier' The dialog is opened again for me.

Comment: Yes, I'm running the same code, JDK 8. Have you tried going step by step in Debug mode and check if it actually goes through the line when it opens the second dialog.

Comment: With the debug my second window does not too open.... Seriously this program makes crazy

Comment: fast snail has also managed to open the second window: http://i.imgur.com/PalDPji.gif

Comment: it's good, i reinstalled jdk 8 and i have my second window but i must to click two times on OK for the windows stops